# Periodic execution of a pthread with limited cpu time

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, real-time

I am on Linux, doing C++ with pthreads, everything is on SCHED_RR. Everything seems to work fine so far. Now I have a thread that does a never ending calculation, lets say it continuously updates a state of something. I want it to execute, lets say every 10 milliseconds for no more than 1 millisecond. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: yes by using a real time system

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. That thread could:

1. Set and alarm for 1ms hence with a suitable signal handler
2. Start working
3. When the alarm goes the signal handler sets a condition to
   get the calculation to stop
4. After the handler returns the calculation continues, but will stop ASAP on observing that the stop condition is set
5. Sleeps for 9ms.

Alternatively (and much more easily) you could set the thread's priority lower. This will cause the OS to schedule your calculation thread only when there is nothing more important going on. The only hard bit is working out whether a large or small priority value means more or less important...

Comment: You are right, something like your proposal is possible. The thing is, that if a single iteration of the calculation takes longer than 1ms it is hard to implement. The second proposal, using a low priority, does not quarantee that the thread runs at predefined times and only for a predefined ammount of time.